# leaflet instantiate from map object

Tags: angular, leaflet, ngx-leaflet

I have a Leaflet Map in one of my Components in an Angular Project (using ngx-leaflet).
I store the Map Object from `onMapReady(event: L.Map)` in a Service so that I don't need to draw the Map again later.
After navigating to a different component and then back, I don't want to instantiate a new Map and draw everything new.

How can I use the stored L.Map on my leaflet map.

Right now I instantiate my map like this

```
<div
  style="height: 100%;"
  leaflet
  [leafletOptions]="this.mapService.options"
  [(leafletLayersControl)]="this.mapService.layersControl"
  (leafletMapReady)="onMapReady($event)"
>
```

Comment: It makes sense to store the map instance in a service if you want to change something in the map from another component, for example add a marker or pan the map. If you navigate to another component and then get back to the map component it will mount again. You do not need to reuse the saved map instance there

Comment: The question is, how do I reuse the saved map instance